# Writing a function in python that makes a new file with a book's text, but not the preamble or license information but its doing the opposite

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that makes a new file with a book's text, but not the preamble or license information. However, it seems to be making a new file with the preamble and license information but not the text!! If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import os

def remove_preamble_and_license(file_name):
  new_file_name = file_name[:-4] + "-new.txt"
  
  with open(file_name, "r") as old_file, open(new_file_name, "w") as new_file:
    lines = old_file.readlines()
    
    start_line = -1
    end_line = -1
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
      if "*** START OF" in line:
        start_line = i
      elif "*** END OF" in line:
        end_line = i
        break
    
    old_file.seek(0)
    
    for i, line in enumerate(old_file):
      if i < start_line or i > end_line:
        new_file.write(line)
```

It seems to be all in working order aside from doing the opposite that I am looking for it to do lol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert your condition:

```
    for i, line in enumerate(old_file):
      if start_line <= i <= end_line:
        new_file.write(line)
```